# Real hwnd from the point

Tags: winapi

When we use `WindowFromPoint` winapi function we usually can get the case, when Point specifies to some control within a window. And in such cases `WindowFromPoint` returns handle to that control, not to the window that handles that control.

For example in my small test application if I point to the "body" of chrome browser I get the control with class = `Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND` and its hwnd.

But what I need is to get the "parent" window for that control (which is obviously should be the chrome window).

Comment: By 'pointer', you mean 'handle'.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: yep, window handle. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traverse the parents using [`GetAncestor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633502%28VS.85%29.aspx) passing `GA_PARENT`. This differs from calling `GetParent()` which will return the owner if the window is a top-level window.

Comment: Yep, but seems like `GA_ROOT` better fits my expectations, doesn't it?

Comment: @zerkms Maybe `GA_ROOT` is better, I'm not sure exactly which window you are looking for. Only you know that!  ;-)

Comment: regular window that is top container for all controls, the one with title and minimize/maximize/close buttons.

Comment: @zerkms In that case then `GA_ROOT` will give you the top-level window.

Comment: okay, thanks. /me pretended that he got the difference between second `GetAncestor()` arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use [GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Keep traversing until you find the desktop window.